# Adding custom meta

Tags: php, seo, atk4

How can I add custom tags (for SEO) in Agile Toolkit (atk4)?

Answer (score 1):

Like with any template, you can add additional text into it through something like this:

```
$object->add('Text')->set('...');
```

in your case you will be adding it into $api class.

http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/metatags

Answer (score 1):

I did this with the following steps on ATK 4.1.1

1. Make a copy of /atk4/templates/shared/shared.html into /templates/default
   Always make a copy in our own website directory so we can still upgrade ATK later by overwriting the atk4 directory.
2. Edited the shared.html you just created and add the following lines after the existing meta statement for Content-Type

   <meta name="description" content="<?metadesc?>Default description here<?/?>
   <meta name="keywords" content="<?metakeywords?>keyword, keyword, keyword...<?/?>

Now you will have your default description and keywords on all pages.
 3. Finally, in /page/....php, put specific tags using the
    following lines

```
$p->api->template->set('page_title','page title goes here');
$p->api->template->set('metadesc','Page description goes here');
$p->api->template->set('metakeywords','keyword1','keyword2','keyword3');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Seo-related controller as well:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/blob/master/misc/lib/Controller/Seo.php

You can use this by adding it into the API inside init();

```
$this->add('Controller_Seo');
```

Then it would simply copy certain tags from page's templates into  section. The source should be simple enough to read through and understand the concept.